# verify xml file + how to set the xmllint command as silent mode

Tags: xml, linux, bash, solaris

I use the command xmllint in order to verify the xml file on linux machine

what I need is silent mode no output , and my verification will be only with exit code ( $? )

as we see here when when the xml is wrong I get error on standard output even I set the --noout flag

```
xmllint --noout CreDefault.XML
Default.XML:16: parser error : Opening and ending tag mismatch: Networks    line 6 and root
orrectiveActions/><fallback/></ErrorHandler></C></T><Vars/></G></Generic></ro   ot>
                                                                              ^
Default.XML:16: parser error : Premature end of data in tag root line 1 
  orrectiveActions/><fallback/></ErrorHandler></C></T><Vars/></G></Generic></ro   ot>
```

is it possible to configure the command as silent mode?
So I can check the $? Only?

what I need is:

```
xmllint --noout CreDefault.XML

echo $?

1
```

Comment: Just redirect the output to `2>/dev/null`?

Comment: Is it on standard output then? `>/dev/null`? Or both `>/dev/null 2>&1`?

Comment: I try also these and I get the same errors

Comment: `2>/dev/null` worked just fine for me here. What command are you trying exactly?

Comment: xmllint --noout  temp.xml 2>/dev/null
temp_inventory.xml:9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<ranges/>
^
warning: failed to load external entity "2"

Comment: as you see here from my last post , its print the errors even I set 2>/...

Comment: Did you put a space between `2` and `>`? That `failed to load external entity "2"` error seems to indicate that `xmllint` saw `2` as an argument.

Comment: no I dont have space between 2 to /dev/null ( I put that 2>/dev/null )

Comment: Then I don't see how it could not be working and how you could be getting that error output/message. I also notice that you've used at least four different filenames during this conversation. Are you sure you are looking at the output you think you are looking at when you test this? Have you run this command manually and seen it not work? This is linux and a shell/shell script, right?

Comment: That shouldn't make a difference. What do you get as output if you run `xmllint /tmp/fjkleflje 2>/dev/null`? Anything?

Comment: I will  give example of other file --> xmllint --noout /tmp/temp_.xml  2>/dev/null
/tmp/temp_.xml:9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<ranges/>
^
warning: failed to load external entity "2"

Comment: xmllint  /tmp/temp_.xml 2>/dev/null
/tmp/temp_.xml:9: parser error : Extra content at the end of the document
<ranges/>
^
warning: failed to load external entity "2"

Comment: What shell is this? I suppose it is possible that it doesn't understand the `2>` redirection syntax (but I thought that was entirely portable). Other than that or some typo I can't see how this can be happening offhand.

Comment: yes you right , I change it to bash and now its works ( before it was tcsh )

Comment: Ah, (t)csh is weird and crufty. Using correct tags possibly would have helped here.

Comment: ok thx post your answer and I will vote for you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't see any way to get `xmllint` to silence itself which means if you really don't want to see the error output you just have to redirect it away yourself.

```
xmllint --noout CreDefault.XML 2>/dev/null
```

(Note from discussion in comments this does not work in `(t)csh` shells.)

Comment: please add remark about the shell ( need to set it as ksh / bash / sh , but not tcsh )

Answer (score 0):

As today, I see that xmllint has a --quiet flag